# C++ Pass exception directly to debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, breakpoints

When I attempt to debug this application the exceptions go straight to the windows error box that prompts "Close the program".

I am fairly certain there is a exception handler that is catching all exceptions (including breakpoints) and making the program crash. I can catch my breakpoint with a Vectored Exception Handler.

How can I send my exception/breakpoint directly to the debugger as a second chance exception essentially skipping over all other exception handlers so that the application does not crash?

Comment: What debugger do you use?

Comment: @user1034749 Ollydbg and visual studio